# проблемы с памятью

Tags: c, указатели, память, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток! Приведу пример кода, в котором укажу лишь те места, где выделяется непосредственно память. Заранее удалю все места, где я эту память освобождаю, чтобы вы, как более опытные программисты в Си, чем я, начинающий, указали мне, как лучше следует с ней обращаться, а главное - показали, из-за чего всё-таки у меня программа в процессе выполнения вылетает с ошибкой **.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова**.

Итак, сам код:

```
    void func(int *intArray, int mode, int length, int **p, int **hufTemp, 
    int *num)
    {
    int *intPtrTemp;
    int *intListTemp, *intListIndexes;
    int *intPtrLength, *intPtrLength_Temp;
    int *intPtrBlCount; 
    int *intPtrNextCode;
    int *intPtrHuffmanTree;
    int *intDictHuffmanTree;
    int count = 0 , max = 0;



    intPtrTemp = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    memset(intPtrTemp, 0, length * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(intPtrTemp, intArray, length * sizeof(int));

    // процесс вычисления count
    intListTemp = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    intListIndexes = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    memset(intListTemp, 0, count * sizeof(int));
    memset(intListIndexes, 0, count * sizeof(int));

    intPtrLength = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    memset(intPtrLength, 0, count * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(intPtrLength, intListTemp, count * sizeof(int));

    intPtrLength_Temp = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    memset(intPtrLength_Temp, 0, count * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(intPtrLength_Temp, intPtrLength, count * sizeof(int));

    // процесс вычисления max
    memcpy(intPtrLength_Temp, intPtrLength, count * sizeof(int));
    intPtrBlCount = (int*)malloc((max + 1)*sizeof(int));
    memset(intPtrBlCount, 0, (max + 1) * sizeof(int));

    intPtrNextCode = (int*)malloc((max + 1) * sizeof(int));
    memset(intPtrNextCode, 0, (max + 1) * sizeof(int));

    intPtrHuffmanTree = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    memset(intPtrHuffmanTree, 0, count * sizeof(int));

    intDictHuffmanTree = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    memset(intDictHuffmanTree, 0, count * sizeof(int));

    memcpy(*p, intPtrLength, count * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(*hufTemp, intDictHuffmanTree, count * sizeof(int));

    *num = count;
}
void main()
{
    char **dictFirstHuffmanTree;
    int intHuffmanTree_Init[19];
    int *p, *_intHuffmanTree, count = 0;

    // вычисление элементов массива intHuffmantree_Init
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    _intHuffmanTree = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    func(intHuffmanTree_Init, 1, 19, &p, &_intHuffmanTree, &count);
    dictFirstHuffmanTree = (char**)malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
    getchar();
}
```

Пара важных моментов.
1. Функция содержится в файле test1.c. Дёргаю я её из файла test2.c. 
2. Если всё писать в одном файле, вот так как я представил (т.е. без освобождения памяти), то всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: Приведенного кода недостаточно. В нем содержится далеко не все.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, что ещё необходимо добавить?

Comment: Необходимо добавить минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы. Вы приведенный код даже скомпилить не пытались.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, сейчас постараюсь исправить.

Comment: Сразу дам совет. Судя по всему, у вас выделяется много кусков памяти и, скорее всего, все они там же и освобождаются, в той же функции. Если да - то проще выделить один большой кусок, которого хватит на всех, расставить соответствующим образом указатели в этот блок, ну, а потом освободить его будет можно одним вызовом `free`...

Comment: @Harry, я добавил скомпилированную версию кода по справедливому замечанию Владимира, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю смысл...`count` у вас 0, к чему все эти выделения 0 байт? Или он спрятан за комментарием? тогда вы в `p` выделяете в `main` места для одного `int`, а в функции пишете `count * sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Harry, я там комментарием отметил, что мол в том месте идёт кусок кода с вычислением значения переменной count.

Comment: Если `count` больше 1, вы пишете лишнее: `memcpy(*p, intPtrLength, count * sizeof(int));` Там же места - для одного `int`...

Comment: @Harry, так .. видимо я пропустил строку `*p = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));`...верно?

Comment: Если вы ее напишете, будет лучше, но если вы просто напишете ее, то потеряете старую память. Ее надо освободить. Кстати, я что-то у вас вообще ни одного `free` не вижу :(

Comment: @Harry, я как раз специально не добавлял `free`, чтобы кто-то из более опытных программистов показал, как и где правильнее всего освобождать её.

Comment: Освобождать там, где она больше не нужна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как минимум:

```
p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Теперь `p` указывает на блок в 4 байта (ну, чтоб не писать `sizeof(int)`, пусть 32-разрядная программа).

Передаете его в функцию. Значение `p` не меняется, теперь это `*p` - раз в функцию передан адрес `p`. И в этот блок вы копируете незнамо сколько памяти:

```
memcpy(*p, intPtrLength, count * sizeof(int));
```

Если `count` больше 1, вы выходите за рамки выделенного блока и перезаписываете служебные структуры менеджера памяти.

Я не говорю, что это единственная ошибка, но дальше я не смотрю - пока что нет смысла...

И вы как, ничего не освобождаете выделенного? Устраиваете себе утечку памяти?

Comment: Во-первых, большое Вам спасибо! Я почему действительно забыл выделить память в самом конце функции!!!
Во-вторых, к Вам большая просба пояснить такой момент: могу ли я в конце функции просто написать `free` для всех указателей, под которые я память выделял?

Comment: Еще раз - если они вам больше не нужны! Например, если вы выделите память `*p = malloc...`, и вернете ее из функции - то в самой функции ее удалять нельзя. Все, что выделено, должно быть освобождено, когда больше не нужно. Нельзя работать с удаленной памятью, нельзя удалять два раза. Вот и все правила, по сути.

Comment: спасибо ещё раз.